# What is the concept behind having a Peer Pressure Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was just going through this list of badges and I find that I can receive what is known as a `Peer Pressure Badge` if I delete a post which has a score of -3 or lower. What is the concept behind this? So, do I need to think about a question which will be down voted to at least a score of -3 and then delete it? How does this encourage posting good questions on the site?

Comment: My take is that it encourages you cleaning up your own wrong answers.

Answer (score 6):

It's for cleaning up answers (or potentially questions).

Every so often someone posts something that the community feels is off topic, offensive, too broad or whatever. This encourages deleting of -3 or worse posts, and hey, if you do that, you get a little badge.  It happens to everyone eventually, but we'd prefer you don't TRY for it ;)

Comment: Also: badges are supposed to be nice surprises to reward good actions that happen naturally. A small number of people do go out of their way to try to get badges (I don't really understand why...), but it's not encouraged. Same with Tumbleweed. Some badges, like this one, are like "That sucks, but you did the right thing"

Comment: @user568458: "Not encouraged" by whom? I would think that people try to gain badges for the same reasons they try to gain reputation, whatever those may be. Jeff Attwood did [say](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/) "badges are supposed to be a little mysterious", but they are still nudges towards desired behaviour.

Comment: Every once and a while, I've thought about going for the peer pressure badge intentionally. I'll try not to drink and ask.

Comment: @user568458 Because they’re shiny collectibles!